# DyanmoDB to MongoDB Migration

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I have AWS dynamoDB database having data.

Need to migrate it into mongoDB.

Is there any tools to achieve this using PHP ?

Comment: Roughly how large is the dataset in dynamodb?

Comment: There is 1 table having almost 9 lakhs of records

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS-DynamoDB-to-MongoDB](https://github.com/JasonGhent/AWS-DynamoDB-to-MongoDB). It may helps tranfer your DyanmoDB to MongoDB.